# How to get an xml file when running mstest

Tags: c#, xml, mstest

I have a class which loads an xml file using the following:

```
Path.Combine( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Xml", documentName );
```

The documents that are being loaded are set to copy to the output directory.  However, when I run mstest the xml file is not being copied to the BaseDirectory.

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer (as odd as it may be).  By adding a testsettings document to the solution the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory seems to be set currectly.